# nautilus does not show external devices folder ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

[image]

[image: Picture2]

As you can see in the first image , I opened 3 folders, 2 folders are from local folders and HDD is an external device. If you attention to the side bar and nautilus You can see just 2 DOTs that mean there are 2 folders in nautilus and there is no third folder !

And in second image I click on nautilus to show me all opened folders but nautilus does not show me HDD folder

Comment: I've edited your post so the images are properly embedded.

Comment: Yeah, it's not actually your fault that they weren't properly embedded; the system doesn't let you embed them unless you have 10+ reputation. (I think?)

Comment: Pro tip: Your question is a bit unclear, I suggest you edit it to improve clarity. Otherwise, you will risk it being closed as "Unclear what you're asking" :)

Comment: I explain with images, What is unclear? I said simply nautilus does not show external devices folders

Comment: Could you add a complete screenshot? There should be a device icon in the launcher that represents the Nautilus window showing the mounted removable device, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a Nautilus window is showing a mounted removable device or partition, it does not get represented by the Nautilus icon in the launcher, but by the disk icon, which should have appeared below your standard launcher icons when you plugged the device in.